# Get java.net.UnknownHostException when use hadoop-ha?

Tags: hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I got an exception when i execute the command `sudo -u hdfs hdfs balancer -threshold 5`.

Here is the Exception.

```
RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
```

Here is my core-site.xml.

```
    <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://nameservice1</value>
    </property>
```

Here is my hdfs-site.xml.

```
    <property>
            <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
            <value>nameservice1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.nameservice1</name>
            <value>nn1,nn2</value>
    </property>
```

Someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when setting up HA. The problem is that I set `dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster` based on the reference documentation. When I replaced `mycluster` with my nameservice name, everything worked!

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-12109

Comment: nice, i add this property in hdfs-site.xml, and run `hdfs dfs -ls /`, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try after putting the port number at  core-site.xml.

```
<property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://nameservice1:9000</value>   
</property>
```

And make sure your machine's /etc/hosts file has entry for nameservice1.
For Example (let you machine IP is 192.168.30.102)

```
127.0.0.1           localhost       
192.168.30.102      nameservice1
```

Comment: When configuring HA, HDFS shouldn't even attempt to resolve the name `nameservice1`, it should rely on `dfs.namenode.rpc-address.nameservice1.nn1` (resp `.nn2`). The way you set it up, how do you configure two namenodes and automatic failover?

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.nameservice1</name>  
  <value>
     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider
  </value>
 </property>
```