# Flink checkpoint on hdfs of HA namenode config

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink, checkpoint

The checkpoint path of flink is an hdfs absolute path like `hdfs://address:port/path`, but when hdfs is on HA mode, how to set the flink configuration for hdfs namenode url change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Hadoop HA ,clusterId is recommended.After doing so,the URI looks like this  hdfs://nameservice_id/path/file.Use this URI instead of 'hdfs://activeNamenodeHost/path'.Hope this helps.

How to set here : [NameNode HA when using hdfs:// URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634344/namenode-ha-when-using-hdfs-uri).

More details here : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html